# Initialize array of interfaces in Golang

Tags: go

Here is an example of variable:

`names := []interface{}{"first", "second"}`

How can it be initialized dynamically, from an array of strings?

Comment: That's not an array, it's a *slice*.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
strs := []string{"first", "second"}
names := make([]interface{}, len(strs))
for i, s := range strs {
    names[i] = s
}
```

Would be the simplest

Comment: Thanks! BTW, I found another way without `make`:

```
  names := []interface{}{}

  string_names := []string{"first", "second"}
  for _, v := range string_names {
    names = append(names, v)
  }
```

Comment: Absolutely. Be aware however that `[]interface{}{}` initializes the array with zero length, and the length is grown (possibly involving copies) when calling `append`. This is usually not a problem, if your arrays are not ridiculously large. If they are, `make` initializes it with full length and never copies it (as the size is known from the start).

Answer (score 42):

`append` initializes slices, if needed, so this method works:

```go
var names []interface{}
names = append(names, "first")
names = append(names, "second")
```

And here is a variation of the same thing, passing more arguments to `append`:

```go
var names []interface{}
names = append(names, "first", "second")
```

This one-liner also works:

```go
names := append(make([]interface{}, 0), "first", "second")
```

For Go 1.18 or later, this is also possible:

```go
names := append([]any{}, "first", "second")
```

---

Yet another option is to first convert the slice of strings to be added to a slice of `interface{}` or `any`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use interface{} array to build it.

```
values := make([]interface{}, 0)
values = append(values, 1, 2, 3, nil, 4, "ok")
```

Then check the type when using the value.

```
for _, v := range values {
    if v == nil {
        fmt.Println("it is a nil")
    } else {
        switch v.(type) {
        case int:
            fmt.Println("it is a int")
        case string:
            fmt.Println("it is a string")
        default:
            fmt.Println("i don't know it")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
new([]interface{})
```

Demo: https://play.golang.org/p/mEyhgQJY277

Answer (score -13):

another way:

```
strs := []string{"first", "second"}
var names []string
names = append(names, strs...)
```

Comment: It's not an interface, isn't it?