# Unmarshalling nested json with multiple type

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

```
[
  1618511472,
  "on-req",
  null,
  null,
  [
    [
      62577595747,
    ]
  ],
]
```

Above is the json response that needs to be parsed
I'm currently using `var resp []interface{}` and `json.Unmarshal` for the raw response. It works for other fields except the array field

When I try to cast the array field `resp[4].([][]interface{})` it doesn't work

Not sure what is the best approach here. Appreciate any help. Thanks beforehand

Comment: You need to do the type assertions one per each nested type. e.g. `resp.[4].([]interface{})[0].([]interface{})[0].(int)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialize array of interfaces in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954030/initialize-array-of-interfaces-in-golang)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to mkopriva's answer

This is the working solution

```
tmp,  ok  := resp[4].([]interface{})
tmp1, ok1 := tmp.([]interface{})
```